# Bootstrap Collapsible buttons. Close button when another is opened

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with bootstrap. Tried everything, no luck yet. My problem is that when I click on the button it collapses nicely but when I click the other one it also opens but the first one does not close. I need close button when another is opened. 
Here's jsbin: http://jsbin.com/sobahuxabu/1
And here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-success" style="padding-bottom:0px; margin-top:15px;">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><font size='3'><i><?php echo'Sveikas(-a) atvykęs(-usi), '.$vardas; ?></i></font></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <b>Pasirinkite Paslaugą:</b>
                    <div class="button-group" id="accordion" aria-multiselectable="false">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" aria-pressed="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top:5px;"><img src="img/vip.png" align="left"><b>VIP</b><img src="img/vip.png" align="right"></button>
                        <div class="btn-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne">
                            <div class="well">
                                Norėdami užsisakyti VIP ant nick: <br>
                                Siųskite žinutę <span class="label label-danger">VIP <?php echo $vardas ?></span> numeriu <span class="label label-danger">1398</span><br>Kaina: <span class="label label-success">1 EUR</span><br></font>


                        </div>
                                </div>


                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" aria-pressed="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><img src="img/Bronze.png" align="left"><b>BronzeVIP</b><img src="img/Bronze.png" align="right"></button>
                        <div class="btn-collapse collapse" id="collapseTwo">
                            <div class="well">
                                Norėdami užsisakyti BronzeVIP ant nick: <br>
                                Siųskite žinutę <span class="label label-danger">VIP <?php echo $vardas ?></span> numeriu <span class="label label-danger">1398</span><br>Kaina: <span class="label label-success">1 EUR</span><br></font>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Do not mind any text written in these buttons.

Comment: Wrap your `button+btn-collpase` in `<div class="panel panel-default">`. http://jsbin.com/pulehewuse/1/ You'll probably have to add some CSS then. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah it works like a charm BUUUUT how do I change that ugly not needed panel background? Could you help me?
Thanks again
Is there anyway not to include that <div class="panel panel-default"> or change it somehow so it won't interact with whole panel?

Comment: In fact I think it still works if you keep only the `panel` class, and remove `panel-default`, then you don't have the border. If it doesn't work as you want, just add another class on that div for CSS purposes so that you can overwrite Bootstrap's CSS rules.

Comment: Thank you once again! You've fixed my issue. Panel class worked flawlessly. THANKS AGAIN!